# How to use LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle as identity provider in many projects?

Tags: rest, symfony, architecture, microservices, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am planning a new microservice project. Single microservices are REST-APIs, the user should authenticate himself with JWT. I want to use the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle for implementing JWT.

How can I make sure that the token is validated correctly on different servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do distributed authentication, make one server be the auth server which the other servers send the token to for authentication.  You can cache the authentication for a (short) period of time, but the data-of-record for the JWT token should be centralized so that if it is invalidated it is invalidated everywhere.